# IKImageBrowserView inside padding

Tags: macos, cocoa, ikimagebrowserview

I'm customizing an `IKImageBrowserView` and I would like to change the space between cells.

I'm using this method `[_imageBrowser setIntercellSpacing:NSMakeSize(0, 0)]` to set the spacing between cells to 0 pixels and it works.

But I notice an inside padding of 10 pixels in the IKImageBrowserView :

[image: Here]

Any Idea?

Comment: Anyone knows if it's possible ?

Comment: In a case where I had a browser view inside a scrolling view, I had some success by messing around with the frame rectangle of the browser view and the bounds rectangle of the clip view, but I didn't get it to work right in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

-setIntercellSpacing: only handle cell **in between**.

I use IKImageBrowserView in vertical, notice this only happened edge between CONTAINER.

tired to find the reason from IKImageBrowserView.h